# If you have a fixed list size, would this code be O(1)

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science

Say for example you are looping through letters in a list, but you have to check for punctuation. Would the following code still be O(n), n being the max characters in a line? I think this because the punctuation list is a fixed size, so that if statement would still be O(1) right?

```
punctuation = [',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '"', ' ', '\t', '\n']   
for letters in line:
        if letters not in punctuation:
            word += letters
```

Comment: if n=10 then O(10)

Comment: This will acutally be O(n x m), you really have two loops the outer loop which loops through each character in the line and then the inner loop which results from the `letters in punctuation` which is a loop through punctuation. Since the loop is nested this has a multiplying effect.

Comment: There's not really enough information to answer the question, and even if there were (and to be clear: there's not), the question is more appropriate for a different Stack Exchange site, like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. If all you care about is the outer loop, the cost is O(n) where n is the length of the line. Depending on the implementation of "in", the cost of the outer loop plus the if is either O(n) (hash set) or O(n*m) (array) where m is the count of punctuation, and ...

Comment: … since m is constant, still O(n). But then there's the concatenation operation, which has its own cost. Conservatively, this brings the whole operation up to O(n^2), and it could be worse than that, depending on how the letter-by-letter concatenation is done.

Comment: See 'x in s' : https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right, since the punctuation list is fixed in size (and not dependent on N), the overall time complexity of your code should be O(N).
As other commentators have pointed out, O(N*M) would probably be more precise, with N being the number of characters you are reading in total, and M the number of punctuation characters.

If you want to optimize there, you could store the punctuation characters in a `set`, where `in` operates in constant time:

```
punctuation = {',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '"', ' ', '\t', '\n'} 
for letter in line:
    if letter not in punctuation:
        word += letter
```